# Reporting with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, report

I'm trying to generate reports using Pandas, grouping by a set of fields:

This is what I'm doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'name1',
        'pretty_name': 'Pretty Name 1',
        'server_name': 'exampleserver.local',
        'provider': 'provider1',
        'type': 'A',
        'status': 'KO'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'name2',
        'pretty_name': 'Pretty Name 2',
        'server_name': 'exampleserver1.local',
        'provider': 'provider2',
        'type': 'B',
        'status': 'OK'
    },
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'name1',
        'pretty_name': 'Pretty Name 1',
        'server_name': 'exampleserver.local',
        'provider': 'provider1',
        'type': 'A',
        'status': 'KO'
    },
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'name1',
        'pretty_name': 'Pretty Name 1',
        'server_name': 'exampleserver.local',
        'provider': 'provider1',
        'type': 'A',
        'status': 'OK'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'name2',
        'pretty_name': 'Pretty Name 2',
        'server_name': 'exampleserver.local',
        'provider': 'provider2',
        'type': 'A',
        'status': 'OK'
    }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

grouped = df.groupby(['server_name', 'provider', 'type', 'status'])['id'].count()
print(grouped.to_string())
```

Which returns:

```
server_name           provider   type  status
exampleserver.local   provider1  A     KO        2
                                       OK        1
                      provider2  A     OK        1
exampleserver1.local  provider2  B     OK        1
```

This is alright, but I would like to add to the result a row containing the total for each provider. I.e.

```
server_name           provider   tot  type  status
exampleserver.local   provider1  3    A     KO        2
                                            OK        1
                      provider2  1    A     OK        1
exampleserver1.local  provider2  1    B     OK        1
```

I'm pretty sure this can be done quite easily with Pandas, but I've spent hours reading documentation with no luck.

Any pointers?

Thanks.

EDIT: I've corrected and extended the example as it didn't really made sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create helper column for compare if match `provider1` with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), convert to integers, so you can use `sum` for count matched values:

```
grouped = (df.assign(new=df['provider'].str.contains('provider1').astype(int))
             .groupby(['server_name', 'provider', 'type', 'status'])['new']
             .agg([('count','size'), ('provider1_count','sum')])
             .reset_index())
print (grouped)
           server_name   provider type status  count  provider1_count
0  exampleserver.local  provider1    A     KO      1                1
1  exampleserver.local  provider2    A     OK      1                0
2  exampleserver.local  provider2    B     OK      1                0
```

EDIT:

You can add `as_index=False` for `DataFrame` and `rename` column:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['server_name', 'provider', 'type', 'status'], as_index=False)['id']
         .count()
         .rename(columns={'id':'counts'}))
```

Then if want new column in position `2` use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df1.insert(2, 'tot', df1.groupby(['server_name','provider'])['counts'].transform('sum'))
print(df1)
            server_name   provider  tot type status  counts
0   exampleserver.local  provider1    3    A     KO       2
1   exampleserver.local  provider1    3    A     OK       1
2   exampleserver.local  provider2    1    A     OK       1
3  exampleserver1.local  provider2    1    B     OK       1
```

And last if need `Multiindex` use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
grouped = df1.set_index(['server_name', 'provider', 'tot','type', 'status'])['counts']
print (grouped)
server_name           provider   tot  type  status
exampleserver.local   provider1  3    A     KO        2
                                            OK        1
                      provider2  1    A     OK        1
exampleserver1.local  provider2  1    B     OK        1
Name: counts, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not really what I was trying to do, I believe my question and example were not very clear, I've made some changes now.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, this does the job perfectly!